# Which Page Box befits cropping PDF?

Tags: pdf

[Following this answer to my SuperUser post, I use Sejda to maximize the crop box without cutting any page content](https://superuser.com/a/1374821/269574). But into which box ought I enter the margins? As I questioned in that post:

> > I must print  PDFs  over 500 pages and with footnotes. All pages are bordered by white blank space, but the white blank space start at different lengths from the border. To wit,  the cutoff and dimensions of the text and images differ for each  page.
>
> It's too inefficient to measure the cutoff of white blank space on each page. How can I deduce the maximum crop size that'd eliminate the most white space, without cropping the text?

[image]

[Here's the source for the picture below](http://help.tracker-software.com/PDFXEdit6/default.aspx?pageid=crop_pages).

[image]

Comment: Is your posted image explaining the boxes not clear enough? And Margins for what???

Comment: Sorry. I can't distinguish these 4 terms still. I meant the new margins, lower inches, that I fancy for the PDF.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you making a pdf to be viewed on screen or a pdf for print? (If you have access to a layout program like InDesign or Illustrator it would probably be easier to just place the pdf in a document with the desired dimensions and export a new pdf.)

Comment: @Wolff Does my edit clarify?

Comment: Yes and no. It's hard to tell without seeing the material you have to work with. It's commonly the trim box which tells the printer which final size the document has (as explained on the page you link to). But I don't understand why you focus on the different white margins. The most important thing is to make all the 500 pages the same size as the paper you wants to print on. If they are all different sizes it's not so easy. If they are all the same size, but with different margins it won't help to crop the pages, they'll need to be scaled as well, but then the font sizes will differ...

Comment: I'm afraid it is *very* difficult to provide a "general" answer. Any cropping would depend upon the actually content of pages. In short, you find a common area where things fit on every page, then crop to that. If your 500 pages are all from the same source, such as a book, then there will be a common content area even if text/images/margins fluctuate overall.